# Use VBA to alignright specific cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and was wondering if someone could help with the following code :

```
Sub Macro1()
    With Selection
        If Cell = "Detail" Then
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Basically, I want to use VBA to alignright any cells with the word "Detail". Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
Sub ToTheRight()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        If r.Value = "Detail" Then
            r.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

This version will color-code the found row:

```
Sub ToTheRight()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        If r.Value = "Detail" Then
            r.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
            Intersect(r.EntireRow, ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Interior.ColorIndex = 27
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm doesn't seem like its aligning any of the cells. I threw a debugger in and highlighted a cell with "Detail" and it worked for that particular cell. Any suggestions?

Comment: **You must Select some group of cells prior to running the macro.**

Comment: Sorry with the questions, but I'm using the Detail section as the first column of my report. What syntax would I use if I wanted to color code the whole row with the word "Detail" in a particular cell?